# Django Admin TabularInline - Getting Foreign Key through a OneToOne Relationship

Tags: python, django, inline, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

As shown below, I want to display one model (**Attendance**) in the admin change view of another (**Event**) as a TabularInline. However, **Attendance** doesn't have a direct ForeignKey pointing to **Event**. Rather, it has a OneToOne relationship with **Registration**, which in turn points to **Event**. Any simple ways of achieving this?

As you can see from the code, I tried to access the **Event** using a method, and pass it into the TabularInline class as **fk_name**, but it threw an error saying *"'myapp.Attendance' has no field named 'get_fk'"*.

**myapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    ...

class Registration(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Attendance(models.Model):
    registration = models.OneToOneField(Registration, primary_key=True, one_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def get_fk(self): 
        return self.registration.event
```

**myapp/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

class AttendanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Attendance
    fk_name = 'get_fk'

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AttendanceInline]
```

My current workaround is to add another 'event' ForeignKey to **Attendance**, but it seems redundant as the same data is already stored inside 'registration'.

Appreciate it if anyone could help!

Answer (score 0):

fk_name should be field name that have Foreignkey relation according to documentation not any property of model.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand fk_name should be a field, but in my case what should I do to point to self.registration.event?